# Converting an std::string into a char array

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion, winsock

I have seen many similar questions but none that seem to be working for my code, I think I am overlooking something basic, maybe you can help.

Right now I'm constructing a string to be sent as a request to the winsock send function, which requires a char [] to be sent.  I need to convert my std::string into a char array (char []).

Currently this is the request that works:

```
char request [] = "GET /gwc/cgi-bin/fc?client=udayton0.1&hostfile=1HTTP/1.0\nHost:www.gofoxy.net\n\n";
```

But I need to change a string of a request to the same data structure.

I appreciate any help!

**edit**:

> I can convert a string to a char *, but how can I use that to get a
>   character array?  I hope I'm not making it more confusing.  Here are
>   two attempts that produce char star's that aren't compatible with the send
>   request when I run:

```
//convert request into a char[]
//char *req_ch = new char[req_str.size()+1];
//hostCh[req_str.size()] = 0;
//memcpy(req_ch, req_str.c_str(), req_str.size());

//char * req = new char[req_str.size() +1];
//std::copy(req_str.begin(), req_str.end(), req);
//req[req_str.size()] = '\0';
```

Comment: Isn't `c_str()` what you are looking for, which returns a pointer?

Comment: So a string to non-const character array? I'd go for a vector constructed with iterators and using `vector::data()`.

Comment: @gosly, An array will decay to a pointer when passed into a function, so it doesn't matter if you pass in a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

If you have some legacy C-style API with a signature like this, where it is expecting a null terminated C-style string:

```
void foo(const char* data);
```

then you can typically do something like:

```
std::string s("my string data");
foo(s.c_str());
```

If you really need an array, or a non-const version of the data, so that the API is this:

```
void foo(char* data, std::size_t len);  // or foo(char[] data, std::size_t len);
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
std::string s("my string data");
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
foo(&v[0], v.size());    // or foo(v.data(), v.size()); in C++11
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need `char[]` or will `char const*` do?

If the latter, c_str() will do what you want.

If the former then you'll need to copy the string into something that does what you want:

```
std::vector<char> buff(str.size() + 1); // initializes to all 0's.
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), buff.begin());
fun_call(&buff[0]);
```

Chances are that you only need the c_str version.  If you're needing this second version then you're reading and probably, hopefully, providing a buff max size.

Comment: Just construct the vector with `str.begin(), str.end()` (or `std::begin` and `std::end`). Since C++11, it also has `data()`, which is meant for accessing the pointer.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see which is faster what with needing to append a '\0'.  An improvement to both might be to use str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size + 1.